# GIF animations in UIImageView in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, xcode6

How am I able to automatically load and run a GIF using UIImageView?

I have imported each image individually but now sure where to go from here.

Also it is to be executed in viewDidLoad, not by using an IBAction of any kind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if `UIImageView` supports gif format but you can give bunch of image to `UIImageView` and it shows them in order. Here is how:

```
let imageView = UIImageView()
imageView.animationImages = imageArray // imageArray is array of UIImage instances
```

There is bunch of other properties and methods that control this behavior in `UIImageView`. You can find more information in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiimageview_class/index.html)